# Cloud Disk Triplicate in AlibabaCloud ECS

Tags: alibaba-cloud-ecs

What is Cloud Disk Triplicate and how can I add in my AlibabaCloud ECS.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 1):

Triplicate technology is nothing but the process of making and distributing three copies of data. It is principle concept of Alibaba Cloud DFS which provides stable and efficient data access and reliability for ECS.

All the Cloud disks and Shared Block Storage offered by Alibaba Cloud ECS Instances are using Triplicate technology. So you can just add a cloud disk to ECS instance

Hope I answered your question.

More about [Triplicate Technology](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/35108.htm)